# Can we create a node group in docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Our current docker cluster has mix size of nodes. i:e some nodes have more memory and storage than other nodes.

Is there any way I can create two separate nodes groups for low end and high end nodes so that I can provision heavy containers on high end nodes only.

I understand using constraint filter(https://docs.docker.com/swarm/scheduler/filter/) I can provision a container on a particular node by ID or name. But again I can;t scale it dynamically if that  node goes down or new nodes are added to the cluster.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't subdivide nodes within a swarm, you need to do it through labels. You apply labels either on the Docker engine - for the old Docker Swarm, or [on the node](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/manage-nodes/#/add-or-remove-label-metadata) for the new Swarm Mode.

Adding a label would be part of your onboarding for a new node - so all nodes have the appropriate labels and the scheduler can manage your services as you want.